# error "pointer hDs is NULL in GDAL GetProjectionRef" when using gdal_rasterize

Tags: shapefile, gdal, png, gdal-rasterize

I want to convert a **.shp** to **.tif**.
So I find the tool gdal_rasterize may help.
But when I input the file it always meet this error:

pointer hDs is NULL in GDAL GetProjectionRef

[image: screenshot]

I have tried different versions of GDAL(1.11.0 and 2.1.0),same error.
The test data is from http://qgis.org/downloads/data/qgis_sample_data.zip

1)Is this wrong because of the data?or the wrong syntax?

2)What is the correct syntax for using gdal_rasterize()?

3)Is there a better way to convert **shp** to **png**(or tif)?coding by myself is ok but I use Java.

Comment: gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 640 480 input.shp output.tif - works for me. If I added bands (-b 1 -b 2 -b 3), I get error: ERROR 6: -b option cannot be used when creating a GDAL dataset.

Comment: I think it's a different situation...

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if you are trying to rasterize into an output raster that doesn't exist.

```
C:\Temp>dir /b test.tif
File Not Found

C:\Temp>gdal_rasterize -b 1 -burn 255 test.shp test.tif
ERROR 10: Pointer 'hDS' is NULL in 'GDALGetProjectionRef'.

Warning 1: The input vector layer has a SRS, but the output raster dataset SRS is unknown.
Ensure output raster dataset has the same SRS, otherwise results might be incorrect.
```

If you want GDAL to create your output raster for you, you need to specify the output extent and pixel size.

Something like:

```
ogrinfo -so test.shp test

INFO: Open of `test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2016-12-21
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (-107.098004, 41.168652) - (-104.171267, 44.190567)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
OID_: Integer (9.0)


gdal_rasterize -te -107.2, 41.0, -104.1, 44.2 -tr 0.01 0.01 -burn 255 test.shp test.tif
```