# Rasterizing polygons in shapefile using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, vector, rasterization

I have the following polygons shapefile consisting of polygons of the five boroughs of New York City from "NYC Open Data", linked here:
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm

I want to take this shapefile and rasterize it to a `.tif` file using `gdal` in Python.

I am using the following python script example to accomplish this task, cited from "Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook 1.0 documentation", linked here:
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html

This is what I am using:

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

gdal.UseExceptions()

# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 25
NoData_value = -9999

# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/NYC_GIS/Boroughs_Test/geo_export_d92842a7-2631-4fe5-ab83-ee070743980c.shp'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'test.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[0])
```

However, this returns the following error message:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0e6d6c7404d4> in <module>
     21 x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
     22 y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
---> 23 target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
     24 target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
     25 band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1892     def Create(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1893         """Create(Driver self, char const * utf8_path, int xsize, int ysize, int bands=1, GDALDataType eType, char ** options=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 1894         return _gdal.Driver_Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1895 
   1896 

RuntimeError: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
```

How do I address this error so that the raster `.tif` file is correctly created and sent to my directory folder? I am not sure why this message is telling me I am creating a 0x0 raster file or what is wrong with the raster I am creating, since it seems like all I have to do to run this code is simply entering my input shapefile, which it seems like I did correctly.

UPDATE (with second attempt at code, incorporating pixel size and setting the projection):

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

# Define NoData value of new raster
NoData_value = -9999

# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/NYC_GIS/Boroughs_Test/geo_export_d92842a7-2631-4fe5-ab83-ee070743980c.shp'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/NYC_GIS/Boroughs_Test/test2.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
proj = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# Create the destination data source
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, 100, 100, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetProjection(proj.ExportToWkt())
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[0])
```

This code runs and outputs a `0`. I am not sure what this means. I then go to open `test2.tif` in QGIS, and all I see is a black square with all `0` values, not the rasterized polygon shapes I expect.

Comment: Try [enabling exceptions](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions) and seeing if you get a more helpful error

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I used `gdal.UseExceptions()` and pasted the new error traceback message in my post. The error is telling my my 0x0 dataset is illegal, and I am not sure what this means, but perhaps it could be an error with my projection. I am trying to figure out what this means, or which step resulted in this problem raster.

Comment: Good point there. I had tried changing the burn value there to 1, but this resulted in a raster that just a black square with all 0 value. I tried your `gdal.Rasterize()` suggestion and it works, and produces the `.tif` raster like I want, but when I open the file in QGIS, it is as well just a black square, with all 0 value pixels. I tried leaving `xRes` and `yRes` blank, but that didn't work. I then tried setting them both to 100, but then the black square was far beyond the extent of the NYC polygons. I am just trying to get the output raster to match the size/extent of the input shapefile.

Comment: Success! This worked! Thank you! I see that the out-of-scale issue is caused by a discrepancy between degrees and lon/lat, but how did you know to choose exactly 0.0001? Sorry I have always been a bit confused between pixel size and resolution. Is 0.0001 the one "correct" size value or just the best approximation? I am just trying to understand so I know how to set the most appropriate pixel size next time.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/corteva/geocube

```py
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

vector_fn = 'C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/NYC_GIS/Boroughs_Test/geo_export_d92842a7-2631-4fe5-ab83-ee070743980c.shp'

out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=vector_fn,
    measurements=["column_name"],
    resolution=(-25, 25),
    fill=-9999,
)
out_grid["column_name"].rio.to_raster("my_rasterized_column.tif")
```

Comment: I really really want to use Geocube as my main tool for raster processing! However, I just cannot seem to get it to download properly. When I try to simply run `pip install geocube` from Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3), I get a a long list of error messages (much too long to post the complete traceback here) including: `WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)`, `Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`, and`ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal`. I am not sure how to address this.

Comment: For geocube, you should use conda to install from conda-forge.

Comment: See: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/installation.html

Comment: I tried using conda-forge via those instructions and received the messages: `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.` and `Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`, ultimately being stuck on `Solving environment: \`. I am not sure how to fix this, but maybe it is something to do with how I set up my system.

Comment: Are you creating a new environment? See the conda install section here: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html

Comment: I was not, but I just tried that, using the instruction you linked to. Now using the `pyproj_env` environment, I ran `conda install -c conda-forge geocube`, which led to the error messages of `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`, `Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`, and then `ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1`.

Comment: I wonder if you need to to create a new environment with python=3.9? Either that or you need to update your conda version so it works with python 3.10.

Comment: I also tried within the `pyproj_env` the following: `conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install geocube`. This led to the same error messages. I then tried running the same from my own `myenv` environment and it appears that everything downloaded after seeing `Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done`. Yet going into Jupyter Notebook and entering `import geocube` resulted in ` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocube'`

Comment: I usually re-install Jupyter in each environment. You could try that.

Comment: I did that and it worked! Well almost. I successfully installed `geocube` through pip, and then re-installed jupyter. However running `from geocube.api.core import make_geocube` reveals the error: `CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown. PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`. Do you know how I can fix this? I am confused because I already have `pyproj` installed.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling GDAL to burn all 0 values with `burn_values=[0]`.

Additionally, setting `xRes` and `yRes` to 100 won't work as your data uses lon, lat coords (1 degree is 111,000m at the equator so 100 degrees is huuuuge).

By the way, the newer `gdal.Rasterize` is easier to use than the old `gdal.RasterizeLayer`.

Particularly there's no need to pre-create the output dataset, just pass an output filename. For example:

```
from osgeo import gdal

# Define NoData value of new raster
NoData_value = -9999

# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'Boroughs.geojson'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'Boroughs.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = gdal.OpenEx(vector_fn)
pixel_size = 0.001  # about 11 metres(ish) use 0.001 if you want roughly 100m 

gdal.Rasterize(raster_fn, source_ds, format='GTIFF', outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, creationOptions=["COMPRESS=DEFLATE"], noData=NoData_value, initValues=NoData_value, xRes=pixel_size, yRes=-pixel_size, allTouched=True, burnValues=1)
```

Comment: Apologies this took so long, but I tried this out, and it is working, but it is just taking so incredibly long that I had to end the code run, and I am not sure if that means there is something wrong with my file. A raster file is produced still, but it is 453 megabytes big, which seems a bit much for my simple NYC example, and it crashes QGIS when I try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you have entered into the Create() function are incorrect. You can find them using the python help function:

```
from osgeo import gdal
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
help(driver.Create)
Create(Driver self, char const * utf8_path, int xsize, int ysize, int bands=1, GDALDataType eType, char ** options=None)
```

In your case, ***you have entered the pixel resolution (xres, yres) inplace of the raster dimensions (xsize, ysize)***:

> target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, x_res,
> y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

To avoid having to manually calculate the raster dimensions, you could rasterise using a reference image as illustrated [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222394/how-to-convert-file-shp-to-tif-using-ogr-or-python-or-gdal/222454#222454).

You have also failed to define a projection system. Consequently, the output image will not be georeferenced. You can do this using the SetProjection() function as follows:

```
vector = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
layer = vector.GetLayer()
proj = layer.GetSpatialRef()
target_ds.SetProjection(proj.ExportToWkt())
```

Your burn value is set to zero. You should probably change this to 1:

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])
```

Comment: Ok, I see that I need actual values for xres and yres. I just replaced them with 100 and 100, and that part of the code runs now. Though I am having some trouble with the `SetProject()` component.

Comment: Particularly I am not sure where in the script to place the function to set the projection. The code runs, but the output .tif file is just a blank 0 value square when I open in QGIS.

Comment: To reiterate, the Create() function requires the number of pixels along each dimension (xsize, ysize) NOT the resolution (xres, yres). The SetProjection() function should be applied before you rasterize.

Comment: Understood, I got rid of xres and yres and just placed 100 and 100 for the xsize and ysize to address the number of pixels. I then placed `target_ds.SetProjection(prok.ExportToWkt())` after `proj = layer.GetSpatialRef()` and before I use `.RasterizeLayer()`, but still the output .tif is all blank 0 value. I pasted my latest attempt in my post to show where I used your suggestions.

Comment: I see the problem. Your burn value is zero. Change this to 1 and it should be OK.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, though I had actually tried that using `gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])`, but unfortunately still a black square of all 0s is shown when brought into QGIS. I really though that would solve the issue, but I am left stumped.

Comment: My only other suggestions would be to check that the polygon overlaps the raster coordinates you are setting in SetGeoTransform(). Also, try increasing the xsize & ysize to 5000 or 10000. This would make sense given that you have set a pixel size of 25m.

Answer (score 0):

I still use gdal 1.11 version and gdal_rastersize with this issue actually, it will need to have the extent of the shapefile (can be retrieved by python gdal):

```
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    extent = geom.GetEnvelope()
```

Then, gdal_rastersize command:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -a_nodata 0 -ot Byte -tr 0.025 0.025  polygon0.shp boroughs.tiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -te 16.2475 43.6218 17.1124 44.3496
```