# Rasterize and sum polygons in Python

Tags: raster, gdal, shapefile, rasterization, geocube

I have the following shapefile of NYC with all 5 Boroughs as separate polygons, called `Boroughs.shp`. Data Source (NYC OpenData): https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm

I assign a separate made-up value, `test_value` to each polygon.

I am trying to take shapefile Boroughs.shp and rasterize each polygon (row) as its own raster layer, where each new raster would each contain a separate and isolated rasterized polygon. I want to create a raster for each borough. This means that the first raster would just be Manhattan rasterized, as if it were the only borough in NYC, and the second raster would just be the Bronx rasterized, as if it were the only borough in NYC, and so on for all of the Boroughs. For each of the 5 rasters produced, I want `test_value` burned into the pixels.

I accomplish this with the following code using the `geocube` package:

```
polygons = gpd.read_file('Boroughs_Test/Boroughs.shp')
polygon_IDs = polygons['ID'].tolist()

for i in polygon_IDs:
    x = polygons.loc[polygons['ID'] == i]
    vector_fn = x
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=vector_fn,
        measurements=["test_value"],
        resolution=(-25, 25),
        fill=-9999,
    )
    out_grid["test_value"].rio.to_raster(str(i) + "_Output_Raster.tif")
```

This works fine, and I have unique, numbered, rasters produced for each borough polygon with the `test_value` value burned in. Now I have 5 new rasters in my directory folder. What I want to do now, which is what I am having trouble with, is simply summing these rasters into a single summed output raster.

I have tried summing with the following code suggested in this post: [Summing all rasters in folder using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419097/summing-all-rasters-in-folder-using-python)

Here is the code:

```
# Create an initial array
with rasterio.open(all_files[0]) as src:
    result_array = src.read()
    result_profile = src.profile 

# Add on the rest one at a time
for f in all_files[1:]:
    with rasterio.open(f) as src:
        # Only sum the arrays if the profiles match. 
        assert result_profile == src.profile, 'stopping, file {} and  {} do not have matching profiles'.format(all_files[0], f)
        result_array = result_array + src.read()
        
with rasterio.open('Result_raster_NYC.tif', 'w', **result_profile) as dst:
        dst.write(result_array, indexes=[1])
```

and I get the following error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8cd83849a0a8> in <module>()
     10     with rasterio.open(f) as src:
     11         # Only sum the arrays if the profiles match.
---> 12         assert result_profile == src.profile, 'stopping, file {} and  {} do not have matching profiles'.format(all_files[0], f)
     13         result_array = result_array + src.read()
     14 

AssertionError: stopping, file Boroughs_Test\1_Output_Raster.tif and  Boroughs_Test\2_Output_Raster.tif do not have matching profiles
```

For some reason it seems like my rasters are just not lining up, which I cannot figure out, because they were all created from the same polgons shapefile. How can I fix my raster summing code so that I can properly sum these raster files? I am open to separate summing approaches beyond this as well.

Comment: But if the polygons don't overlap, what's the point of summing the rasterised versions (since there's no overlap)?

Comment: Have you seen this example: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html ?

Comment: @alphabetasoup - While yes, you are correct, summing my rasters in this example, with my single value pixels, and no data regions, would ultimately lead to a raster of NYC that is back where I started, e.g. the values remain the same. However, I am using this as an example so that I can have a script where I can insert polygons that do overlap. As far as raster summing, I will have other raster files that will actually have overlapping pixel values that need to be summed. I felt that this example would be the simplest way to get a working script going.

Comment: @snowman2 - Yes I saw that example, and I will surely be looking back to it, since I do need to use zonal statistics for my project. Does geocube have a way that I could set all of my produced rasters to the same extent? I want to set all of my individual polygon rasters to the same extent/bounding box as the initial input NYC shapefile, with all polygons intact. The extent of the shapefile is: `563069.6710568518610671,4483098.0464451070874929 : 609762.2528290073387325,4529951.9860328584909439`, but I do not know how to enter this into geocube. Would this be the "geom" parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`make_geocube`](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#make-geocube) supports a `geom` parameter:

> geom (str, optional) – A GeoJSON string for **the bounding box of the
> data used to construct the grid**. It defaults to EPSG:4326 if a CRS is
> not provided.
>
> Example of adding CRS:
>
> {"type": "Polygon", "crs": {"properties": {"name": "EPSG:3857"}}}

The `geom` param is not very smart, it can't use geometry directly, nor `geometry.__geointerface__` etc. and requires a single feature, not a featurecollection as a string, not a GeoJSON dict.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from shapely.geometry import box
import json

polygons = gpd.read_file('/path/to/input.shp')
polygon_IDs = polygons['ID'].tolist()

# Make a GeoJSON string of the bounding box feature
bbox = gpd.GeoSeries(box(*polygons.total_bounds), crs=polygons.crs)
geom = bbox.__geo_interface__["features"][0]["geometry"]

# Add CRS
geom["crs"] = {"properties": {"name": f"EPSG:{polygons.crs.to_epsg()}"}}

cubes = []
for i in polygon_IDs:
    x = polygons.loc[polygons['ID'] == i]
    vector_fn = x
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=vector_fn,
        measurements=["test_value"],
        resolution=(-25, 25),
        fill=0,
        geom=json.dumps(geom)
    )
    cubes.append(out_grid)
out_grid = sum(cubes)
out_grid["test_value"].rio.to_raster(f"/path/to/Output_Raster.tif", dtype=out_grid["test_value"].dtype)
```

Note I had to add `dtype=out_grid["test_value"].dtype` in `rio.to_raster` to avoid a `TypeError` crash, not sure why.

Comment: Does this perform any attribute summation?

Comment: Nope, question is not actually about summing, it's about getting the input rasters into the same extent so they can be summed and the OP already has code to sum.

Comment: @user2856 - This looks very promising. Though I tried it out and received this error: `RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file '/tmp/Output_Raster.tif' failed: No error`, and I am not sure what the error actually is if it says "No error". I used the same shapefile from before. And yes, my question here was about getting the rasters into the same extent so they can be summed. But once that works, I will try the newly produced same-extent rasters with my summing code to see if they can be successfully summed.

Comment: Just change your output path to a location you can write to. Lesson: don't just copy/paste/run code from StackExchange!

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis did this work?

Comment: I was able to resolve the error, and the code works now, thanks. I can see the output raster now, but I am a bit confused with the results. I see you added the `out_grid = sum(cubes)' line there which would sum all of the rasters I wanted to sum, but I am confused at the summed results I am seeing. In my input polygons shapefile I see that Manhattan had a "test_value" of 636.621, yet looking at `Output_Raster.tif`, the rasterized Manhattan polygon now has a value of -39359.379 (Band 1), and the outer zone within the bounding box has a value of -49995 and I don't know where that came from.

Comment: It's summing the NoData values - change `fill=-9999` to `fill=0`.

Comment: This worked! Solved! Thank you very much! I was not aware that 'sum()' could be used on my geocube objects. That seems so straight-to-the-point and simple, I like it. Is this 'sum()' base python? Or is this sum function part of geocube or gdal?

Comment: @user2856 - I tried using your code suggestion with the `geom` param for adding the bounding box and CRS, but I just receive this error message: `CPLE_OutOfMemoryError: memdataset.cpp, 1513: cannot allocate 1x6404264184 bytes`. It seems the raster summing is just too intensive. Yet my initial code at the top of my post works great, and each raster is produced in a second, with over 500 successfully produced for my real research shapefile with over 500 polygons. Yet somehow adding the `geom` param as shown above just causes it to crash due to a lack of memory, which I don't understand.

Comment: That code works as written using the dataset I used (NYC Boroughs), I can't really debug via comments but looking at your [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420316/trying-to-process-rasters-in-python-and-received-cple-outofmemoryerror-error), your area of interest is just too large and you'll need to do it in chunks. I don't know if geocube supports windowed writing, you may have to use rasterio.

Answer (score 3):

Sum operations on rasters require that the input data share many properties, including having the same CRS, same resolution, and (crucially) the same extent. Because the rasters you mean to sum are covering each of the five boroughs, they inherently have different extents.

Comment: Good point, yes I see that mismatched extents would be an issue, and why of course, differently shaped polygons would have different extents. My goal would be to have all of the rasters have the same extent, which would be the extent of the NYC shapefile, with all borough polygons intact. Do you know how I can set geocube to make all rasters produced share the same extent? I looked at the properties of my NYC shapefile and see that the extent is `563069.6710568518610671,4483098.0464451070874929 : 609762.2528290073387325,4529951.9860328584909439`, but I do not know where to enter this.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to the accepted answer in order to consume less memory since it broke for me when trying to run it at 0.1º resolution

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from shapely.geometry import box
import json

polygons = gpd.read_file('Shapefile.zip')
polygon_IDs = polygons['ID'].tolist()
len(polygon_IDs)

# Make a GeoJSON string of the bounding box feature
bbox = gpd.GeoSeries(box(*polygons.total_bounds), crs=polygons.crs)
geom = bbox.__geo_interface__["features"][0]["geometry"]

# Add CRS
geom["crs"] = {"properties": {"name": f"EPSG:4326"}}
out_grid = None
for i in polygon_IDs:
    cubes = []
    print(i)
    x = polygons.loc[polygons['ID'] == i]
    vector_fn = x
    partial_out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=vector_fn,
        measurements=["feature_name"],
        resolution=(-0.1, 0.1),
        fill=0,
        geom=json.dumps(geom)
    )
    cubes.append(partial_out_grid)
    if out_grid is not None:
        cubes.append(out_grid)
    out_grid = sum(cubes)
out_grid["feature_name"].rio.to_raster(f"Output_Raster_0_1.tif", dtype=out_grid["feature_name"].dtype)
```