# Trying to process rasters in python and received CPLE_OutOfMemoryError error

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, memory, geocube

I have a script that does some geoprocessing, that makes sense in a test run, but when I actually try to use it with my actual dataset, appears to totally overload my computer with memory needs, and I am very confused about about to actually fix this. I am using the `rasterio` and `geocube` packages.

I have a polygons shapefile here called polygons. This shapefile has three columns with unique values: `Blue`, `Red`, `Green`, and `test`. I want to, for each of these columns, rasterize each polygon, and then sum. So I would then have a raster of all `Blue` values summed, and then of all `Red` values summed, and of all `Green` values summed, and then of all `test` values summed. I then want to divide each of the summed color rasters by the summed test raster. to produce a final Blue, Red, and Green raster output. Here is my code:

```
list = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green', `test']

for i in list:
    polygons = gpd.read_file('Colors/Polygons.shp')
    polygon_IDs = polygons['Polygon_ID'].tolist()

    # Make a GeoJSON string of the bounding box feature
    bbox = gpd.GeoSeries(box(*polygons.total_bounds), crs=polygons.crs)
    geom = bbox.__geo_interface__["features"][0]["geometry"]

    # Add CRS
    geom["crs"] = {"properties": {"name": f"EPSG:{polygons.crs.to_epsg()}"}}

    cubes = []
    for j in polygon_IDs:
        x = polygons.loc[polygons['Polygon_ID'] == j]
        vector_fn = x
        out_grid = make_geocube(
            vector_data=vector_fn,
            measurements=[i],
            resolution=(-25, 25),
            fill=0,
            geom=json.dumps(geom)
        )
        cubes.append(out_grid)
    out_grid = sum(cubes)
    out_grid[i].rio.to_raster(f"Colors/Output_Raster_{i}.tif", dtype=out_grid[i].dtype)

d = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
test = 'Colors/Output_Raster_test.tif'
folder = Path('Colors')

src = rasterio.open(test) 

for f in folder.glob("*.tif"):
    if any(color in f.name for color in d):

        med = rasterio.open(f) 
        new_raster = med.read(1)/src.read(1)

        # write raster
        profile = src.profile
        profile.update(
            dtype=new_raster.dtype,
            count=1,
            compress='lzw')
        with rasterio.open(f"Colors/Output_Raster_{f.name}.tif", 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(new_raster, 1)
```

However, when I run this code I received this error: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.96 GiB for an array with shape (25631, 31233) and data type float64`

I then delete files to make space and then receive this error: `CPLE_OutOfMemoryError: memdataset.cpp, 1513: cannot allocate 1x6404264184 bytes`

I am guessing this means that my code is just to intensive to run smoothly and just requires too much memory. But I am not sure which part is using up all of the memory. I am guessing it probably has to do with all of the raster summing, but I am not sure. Would anyone perhaps know how I might alter my code so that it will not require so much memory or what steps I might be going wrong in?

Comment: I'd explore using windowed read/writes:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#windowed-reading-and-writing

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried the first part of my script, starting from `list = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green', test']` and down to `out_grid[i].rio.to_raster(f"Colors/Output_Raster_{i}.tif", dtype=out_grid[i].dtype)` just to see if those rasters actually would get made. They did not. After a good 10 or so minutes running, nothing happened, and eventually the memory just ran out again and I am left with no output rasters and this error message: `CPLE_OutOfMemoryError: memdataset.cpp, 1513: cannot allocate 1x6404264184 bytes`. I would like to use windows, but I'm not sure if they work with `geocube`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a non `geocube` way using `rasterio` and `fiona` (could also use the higher level `geopandas` which uses fiona under the hood).  This

- loops through small chunks (aka a `rasterio.windows.Window`) and the features in your polygon dataset,
- rasterizes the features just in the small chunk area,
- sums the chunks,
- writes each summed chunk to the appropriate part of the output raster

```py
import fiona as fio
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.features import rasterize
from rasterio import windows


#########################################
# Change these to suit your data
polys = 'your_data.shp'
poly_value_field = 'Value'
sum_raster = 'your_output.tif'
pixel_size = 25  # adjust appropriately if using a geographic CRS e.g. 0.0025
dtype = 'float32'
windows_shape = (1024, 1024)
all_touched = False  # only pixels with centre covered by polygon
#########################################


def get_windows(window_shape, image_shape):
    """Convenience generator for non-overlapping Windows"""
    win_rows, win_cols = window_shape
    img_rows, img_cols = image_shape
    offsets = product(range(0, img_cols, win_cols), range(0, img_rows, win_rows))
    image_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=img_cols, height=img_rows)

    for col_off, row_off in offsets:
        window = windows.Window(
            col_off=col_off,
            row_off=row_off,
            width=win_cols,
            height=win_rows)

        yield window.intersection(image_window)


with fio.open(polys) as features:
    crs = features.crs
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = features.bounds
    transform = rio.Affine.from_gdal(xmin, pixel_size, 0, ymax, 0, -pixel_size)
    out_shape = (int((ymax - ymin)/pixel_size), int((xmax - xmin)/pixel_size))

    with rio.open(
            sum_raster, 'w',driver='GTiff',
            height=out_shape[0], width=out_shape[1], count=1,
            dtype=dtype, crs=crs, transform=transform,
            tiled=True, options=['COMPRESS=LZW']) as raster:

        for window in get_windows(windows_shape, out_shape):
            window_transform = windows.transform(window, transform)
            window_shape = (window.height, window.width)  # can be smaller than windows_shape at the edges
            window_data = np.zeros(window_shape)

            for feature in features:
                    value = feature['properties'][poly_value_field]
                    geom = feature['geometry']
                    d = rasterize(
                        [(geom, value)],
                        all_touched=all_touched, out_shape=window_shape, transform=window_transform
                    )
                    window_data += d  # sum values up

            raster.write(window_data, window=window, indexes=1)
```

Comment: This works great! My output sum raster of all 500-some rasters was successfully produced! Thank you very much!

Comment: I do have a question though. I see at the top of the script you set both the vector and rasters to `EPSG:5070`. Does this mean that the output rasters will both match the input shapefile as `EPSG:5070`, such that when I open the input shapefile and the output rasters in QGIS they will directly overlap? I ask since I am not seeing shapefile and rasters are overlapping.

Comment: They do overlap for me, because the input shapefile is the same CRS, but you shouldn't use that CRS just because I did in my example, use whatever \coordinate system you want. See update.

Comment: My input shapefile is `CRS: EPSG:2228 - NAD83 / California zone 4 (ftUS) - Projected` and the output rasters are `CRS: EPSG:5070 - NAD83 / Conus Albers - Projected`, and they do not line up in QGIS. I tried assigning the rasters to the projection of the vector, but this is not working in QGIS. I am thinking that perhaps just restarting your script and setting the CRS to EPSG:2228 would work then. Also, in your updated script above for the line: `pixel_size = 25  # adjust appropriately if using a geographic CRS e.g. 0.0025`, how does pixel size determine the CRS?

Comment: That is why I said in the script comments `# Change these to suit your data` Just re-run the script (with my changes, copy the whole script, I made a change further down).  Pixel size doesn't determine CRS. You choose an appropriate pixel size for your CRS.

Comment: The change I made further down is to set the crs to the shapefile crs

Comment: Ah ok, got it, thanks, sounds good, I retried the script, though it has been running for quite a while now, though I am guessing this is just how big the output rasters will be? For context, I am trying to accomplish this so that I can use `zonal_stats` from `rasterstats` to run zonal statistics on the rasters with the input polygons shapes, but I am thinking I would first need to get everything actually first overlapping. I will report back once this script finishes running, but I did use gdal to change the raster to EPSG:2228, and they are still not lined up, so I am out of answers there.

Comment: You're converting polygons to raster so you can run zonal stats? At first glance it sounds like it'd be easier to do it all as vector overlay then tabular operations - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem