# Summing rasters in python with different shapes

Tags: raster, gdal, polygon, rasterio, geocube

I have a polygons shapefile with many individual overlapping polygons, each containing a unique value in the "Value" column. I want to iterate over each polygon in this shapefile (feature in other words) and rasterize the polygons, with the "Value" value burned in. I have 500 polygons, so now I would have 500 rasters, with each containing a single isolated rasterized polygon with the "Value" value burned in. I then want to sum all of these rasters and then take that raster sum and write it to a raster .tif file.

I am using python and the `geocube` and `rasterio` packages for this task. Here is my code so far:

```py
Polygons = gpd.read_file('Polygons.shp')
polygons = Polygons

for i in polygon_IDs:
    x = polygons.loc[polygons['Polygon_ID'] == i]
    vector_fn = x
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=vector_fn,
        measurements=["Value],
        resolution=(-25, 25),
        fill=0,
    )
    out_grid["Value].rio.to_raster(str(i) + "_Output_Raster.tif")
```

This works. I now have 500 raster files containing just the specific rasterized polygon with the "Value" value burned in. Now, what I want to do, is go to the folder all of these rasters were sent to, and sum them all together. I am using this code to try this:

```py
#Get all files that end with ".tif"
all_files = glob.glob('*.tif')

# Create an initial array
with rasterio.open(all_files[0]) as src:
    result_array = src.read()
    result_profile = src.profile 

# Add on the rest one at a time
for f in all_files[1:]:
    with rasterio.open(f) as src:
        # Only sum the arrays if the profiles match. 
#         assert result_profile == src.profile, 'stopping, file {} and  {} do not have matching profiles'.format(all_files[0], f)
        result_array = result_array + src.read()
        
with rasterio.open('Result_raster.tif', 'w', **result_profile) as dst:
        dst.write(result_array, indexes=[1])
```

This leads to this error: `AssertionError: stopping, file 1Output_Raster.tif and 2Output_Raster.tif do not have matching profiles`

I then remove the `assert result_profile == src.profile, 'stopping, file {} and {} do not have matching profiles'.format(all_files[0], f)` line and re-run and receive this error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1294,1294) (1,1306,1411)`

Looking at the raster files I am trying to sum in QGIS, I see they are just rasterized polygons with the "Value" value burned in, but with no data to show outside the shape. So they are basically missing a bounding box. Because of this it seems that there is no common bounding box for each of these rasters, and that may be why it is not working to simply add them up? How can I fix this so that I can get the raster sum output I want?

Comment: You're not using the `geom` param like I showed you last time you asked about the [same error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419509/2856).

Comment: My apologies for forgetting about that post, you are right, you explained it well for me. Though I tried using the `geom` param today in my code, it technically works, but takes so much memory it crashes. I will post this update on the original post.

Comment: I've [posted a workaround](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420821/2856) to the memory error using rasterio windows